# 6th generation iPod Nano video out

Tags: video, ipod, ipod-nano

Is the 6th/7th generation iPod Nano capable of sending video out through the 32 pin connector into a suitable digital dock?

If so, could the camera adapter kit be used as it can for the iPad to stream digital video out to a DAC?

Answer (score 1):

6th and 7th gen iPod nanos aren't capable of playing videos to the screen, so I highly doubt they'll output any video to the dock.

(They're probably entirely missing the video decoding hardware needed to do either.)